# Asp.net Wildcard, how to identify and populate a label based on a text box input

Tags: c#, asp.net, wildcard, contains

I have a web form with a text box for users to input postcodes. However i do not want to Accept postcodes beginning with BT or JE.

i have researched and looking at the contains function with C# however struggling to get it to work.

```
        if (Txt_Postcode_input.Text.Contains("*BT*"))
        {
            // display label
            Postcode_Not_Accepted.Text = "Not Accepted";
        }
        else
        {
          //insert lead
        }
```

is there something wrong or should i be looking at something else?.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (Txt_Postcode_input.Text.StartsWith("BT")) 
{
    dothis();
}
else
{
    whatever();
}
```